# #mmenu menu icon shows no reaction

Tags: android, jquery, mmenu

I try to use the mmenu-plugin, but I've got the problem, that on an android-smartphone there is a thick black vertical line between menu-item and content - and on an iphone the menu-icon does not react or only with a very long delay (have to touch several times, before it reacts.? Is there anybody who has build it in sucessfully?

It's the second experience with such kind of slidemenu-plugins, the other one was the http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/, the menu - icon didn't react well, too.

I need a multilevel one.

Thanks and regards
glupto

Comment: pushing the page out of view could be slow due to loads of content like images, videos etc. Does it help if you reduce the amount of content in the page?

Comment: No, there are a lot of feeds, that I have to show as content but normally the page loads fast. And it's only a problem with iphone. Don't know why. You can look here http://nachrichtentisch.de/_stickyheaderneu5.php. kind regards glupto